# FTP_PUT in PHP and the remote File System

Tags: php, file, upload

```
ftp_stream
The link identifier of the FTP connection.

remote_file
The remote file path.

local_file
The local file path.

mode
The transfer mode. Must be either FTP_ASCII or FTP_BINARY.

startpos
The position in the remote file to start uploading to.
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

I still have difficulty understanding many things from that link.

**Question:**

```
$upload = ftp_put($newconn->conn,$destination,$source, FTP_BINARY);
```

what will be destinate and source actually?

`$destination` is remote file and `$source` is just file?

and if we want to put the uploaded content to some respective folder. do we have to startpos
location as that folder location?

Update:

I am using this:

```
$filename = "message.txt";
$source = getcwd()."/".$filename;
echo "The source file path is: ". $source;
echo "<br />";
$destination=getcwd()."/"."ftpsend/";
echo "The destination file path is: ". $destination;
echo "<br />";
$upload = ftp_put($newconn->conn,$destination,$source, FTP_BINARY);
```

I am getting this error:

[image: Error]

In Filezilla it shows this path →
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php#89986) in the documentation

> you can't put a path to the destination file

So you have to use `ftp_chdir()` to specify the destination directory.

You shouldn't concatenate the destination directory to `getcwd()`, since that's a pathname on your local machine, not the remote server.

```
$filename = "message.txt";
$source = getcwd()."/".$filename;
echo "The source file path is: ". $source;
echo "<br />";
$destination="/app.trafficopedia.com/ftp";
echo "The destination file path is: ". $destination;
echo "<br />";
ftp_chdir($newconn->conn,$destination);
$upload = ftp_put($newconn->conn,$filename,$source, FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: Hi, Please see my updated post. Thanks for acknowleding.

Comment: Still there are errors → http://app.trafficopedia.com/ftp/

Comment: Filezilla shows this path. Can we test it through manual file path → /app.trafficopedia.com/ftp

Comment: Is `app.trafficopedia.com` actually a directory name, or is just the name of the remote server?

Comment: This is the current status of the code https://ibb.co/M6Qqx7B but it still generates bugs. I tried with the path shown in filezilla.

Comment: app.trafficopedia.com is a directory name sir.

Comment: Please see this → https://ibb.co/r3rcK7N Also see this → https://ibb.co/WtzQ3Z1

Comment: Don't prepend `getcwd()` to the destination. the top-level directory is `app.trafficopedia.com`

Comment: Yes, but I also did it with putting direct paths still it generates the same path →https://ibb.co/M6Qqx7B

Comment: `$source` has to be a file, not a directory.

Comment: Thanks, does this code make any sense: https://ibb.co/FY0Krjf or still I am faltering.

Comment: According to w3school definition https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_ftp_put.asp all 3 mandatory segments are connection and 2 paths.

Comment: Is `ftp_put` not for transferring files within the same server and two different folders(Tow different location)?

Comment: No, ftp_put is for transfering files from a client machine to an FTP server.

Comment: what FTP function will we use for transferring files between two live servers?

Comment: If you want to transfer from server1 and server2, use `ftp_get` to download from server1, then `ftp_put` to upload to server2.